# Sort dynamic List<T> for a specific property

Tags: c#, linq, list, generics

I have a generic list which I want to order by two properties, priority and then by description to fill a drop down list.

I know that when I now exactly the type of the object list I can do

```
list = list.Orderby(x=>x.property1).ThenOrderBy(x=>x.property2).
```

My question is how can I check if the property1 and property2 exist on the object and then sort my list based on those properties.

Comment: if those properties belongs to an interface or class you can use a constraint on T

Comment: Compiler will do it for you. If they don't exist compilation will fail.

Comment: do you mean a `List<dynamic>`?

Comment: Yes I mean List<dynamic>

Comment: You can't know at compile-time.  `dynamic` moves all type-checking to run-time.  What would you do differently if the underlying type did _not_ have those properties?

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using a generic list, the compiler will check that for you.

For example: if you write code like

```
List<Object> list = new List<Object>();
var newlist = list.Orderby(x=>x.property1).ThenOrderBy(x=>x.property2);
```

you'll get a compiler error on property1 & property2 because the compiler won't find these properties on the Object type.

If you want to support different types that each should have those 2 properties, the correct way would be to create an interface with those 2 properties, let each of the types you want to support implement that interface and then use a constraint on T like Arturo proposed.

Something like

```
interface ICanBeSorted
{
   string property1 {get;}
   string property2 {get;
}

public List<T> MySortMethod(List<T> list) where T : ICanBeSorted
{
   return list.OrderBy(x=>x.property1).ThenOrderBy(x=>x.property2);
}
```

This method will be able to sort all types that implement interface ICanBeSorted.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the selector in a `try-catch` block :

```
Func<dynamic, dynamic> DynamicProperty(Func<dynamic, dynamic> selector)
{
    return x =>
    {
        try
        {           
            return selector(x);
        }
        catch (RuntimeBinderException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

Usage :

```
var sorted = list
    .OrderBy(DynamicProperty(x => x.property1))
    .ThenBy(DynamicProperty(x => x.property2));
```

Answer (score 0):

well, the way you are trying to do it is a bad idea. Try using if-else or switch case first and then put your code to order them the way you want accordingly.